# How can I open my child database with FaunaDB Shell?

Tags: faunadb

I have a FaunaDB database of "RaspberryPi" and their child database of "00000000790f4c7c" as following:
[image]

So how can I open the child database "00000000790f4c7c"?
I've tried to open **00000000790f4c7c** and **RaspberryPi/00000000790f4c7c**, but both just get errored.

```
MacBook-Air:~ takeyuki$ fauna shell RaspberryPi/00000000790f4c7c
Error: Database 'RaspberryPi/00000000790f4c7c' doesn't exist
MacBook-Air:~ takeyuki$ fauna shell 00000000790f4c7c
Error: Database '00000000790f4c7c' doesn't exist
```

Thank you for your kindly help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the shell doesn't have great support for nested databases at the moment. You want to either create an endpoint to the parent say "RaspberryPi" with an admin key then invoke `fauna shell 00000000790f4c7c` or you can create a key inside RaspberryPi with CreateKey({role: "server", database: "00000000790f4c7c"}) and create and endpoint with that secret, or access it directly with `fauna shell --secret XXX` where `XXX` is the secret from the created key.

The key (no pun intended) is that whatever your current endpoint is `fauna shell $db` will try to access a database $db nested inside the database point at by that endpoint. By default that's / so `fauna shell $db` lands in `/$db` if you have an endpoint `/$parent` and invoke `fauna shell $child` then you'll end up in `/$parent/$child`. If you leave off `$db` then you end up in whatever database the endpoint is pointing at. so if you have an endpoint `n` components deep you have access to it and all it's children at `n + 1` only.

Better support for nested databases is on the roadmap, because that's not particularly ergonomic.

Comment: I can open the nested database successfully with ```fauna shell --secret XXX```, thanks!